# Limit number of duplicate elements within an array to a given value

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates

In Ruby, if I have an `array` with duplicates in it and a given value `n`:

```
array = [1,56,1,245,56,1,56,1,56,1,56]

n = 2
```

How could I limit the number of duplicates within the `array` to `n` whilst also retaining the positioning of the remaining elements to produce this?

```
array = [1,56,1,245,56]
```

Comment: do duplicates go sequentially?

Comment: If they can retain their original positioning that would be ideal. So if the `array = [1,56,1,245,56,1,56,1,56,1,56]` then if it were possible to return `array = [1,56,1,245,56]` that would be ideal. I'll redit the question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def ndup(list, n)
  cnts = {}
  list.select do |item|
    cnts[item] ||= 0
    cnts[item] += 1
    cnts[item] <= n
  end
end

ndup([1,56,1,245,56,1,56,1,56,1,56], 2)
#=> [1, 56, 1, 245, 56]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def ff(array, n)
  occurances = Hash.new(0)
  array.uniq do |element|
    occurances[element] = occurances[element] < n ? occurances[element].next : n
    [element, occurances[element]]
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to produce a `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)` when testing this.

Comment: @AlexanderSwann, I posted the original from my mobile. Fixed now. Still, the other solution is better.

Comment: No worries, it's always good to see varied solutions on here. Thanks for fixing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using a counting hash is the way to go here, but here's an alternative:

```
array.each_with_index.
      group_by(&:first).
      values.
      flat_map { |a| a.first(n) }.
      sort_by(&:last).
      map(&:first)
  #=> [1, 56, 1, 245, 56]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
enum = array.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 56, 1, 245, 56, 1, 56, 1, 56, 1, 56]:each_with_index> 
h = enum.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {  1=>[[1, 0], [1, 2], [1, 5], [1, 7], [1, 9]],
  #     56=>[[56, 1], [56, 4], [56, 6], [56, 8], [56, 10]],
  #    245=>[[245, 3]]} 
a = h.values
  #=> [[[1, 0], [1, 2], [1, 5], [1, 7], [1, 9]],
  #    [[56, 1], [56, 4], [56, 6], [56, 8], [56, 10]],
  #    [[245, 3]]] 
b = a.flat_map { |a| a.first(n) }
  #=> [[1, 0], [1, 2], [56, 1], [56, 4], [245, 3]] 
c = b.sort_by(&:last)
  #=> [[1, 0], [56, 1], [1, 2], [245, 3], [56, 4]] 
c.map(&:first)
  #=> [1, 56, 1, 245, 56]
```